# Can we install Hyper-V and Oracle DB 11g in the same machine ? Is this against Hyper-V's best practices?

Tags: database, oracle11g, virtual-machine, hyper-v

We have a big server which has Hyper-V and some virtual machines running there. Our product has some wierd issues when running on Oracle DB in a virtual machine so we want to install Oracle directly to the physical server. We can limit the RAM and CPU usage of Oracle DB in order to not interfere with Hyper-V. Is this against Hyper-V's best practices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can have both Hyper V and Oracle on the same system. The [best practices](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/11/03/windows-server-2012-r2-hyper-v-best-practices-in-easy-checklist-form.aspx) does not say anything about that ie, nothing has been said that we cannot have Oracle and Hyper-V together on the same system.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you may expect unpredictable stacking of your virtual machines because parent partition always has a priority over child partitions.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/andrew/archive/2011/09/21/a-quick-introduction-to-hyper-v.aspx

On other hand it makes sense if you have a bunch of VMs being used just occasionally.

See also
http://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/4-reasons-your-hyper-v-host-should-only-run-the-hyper-v-role/